# Get Couchbase nodes and indexes through N1QL in Community Edition?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I've been looking for a way to get in the server nodes in a cluster through N1QL.

The role `query_system_catalog` can be used to get the nodes through

```
SELECT * FROM system:node
```

But this role is only available, from what I can see, in the Enterprise edition. Is there a way to get them through n1ql in Community Edition?

Edit:

This is the error shown

````
<N1QL Execution failed, OBJ={u'msg': u'User does not have credentials to run queries accessing the system tables. Add role query_system_catalog to allow the query to run.', u'code': 13014}>```
````

Comment: What versions are you trying this on?

Comment: Community Edition 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

RBAC roles are supported in EE only https://www.couchbase.com/products/editions.

In CE there is no roles. Once user is logged in, the following command should work

```
select * from system:nodes;
```

Comment: When I make a query from the code to n1ql it does ask for `query_system_catalog`

Comment: Would it be fair to say Community Edition does have roles but they are not as fine-grained as the roles supported by EE? In CE the roles are limited to "Admin", "Read-only Admin", and "Bucket Full Access" (for all buckets or for specific buckets). EE on the other hand has a much richer set of access control options.

Answer (score 1):

The Administrator role should be available in CE. Try running the query as Administrator.

Comment: As I commented in the other answer, when I make a query from the code to n1ql it does ask for query_system_catalog role

Comment: If you cannot run the query as administrator that is a serious bug. The administrator should be able to do everything. If you can run the query as administrator, but it the typical error message when you try to run it using inadequate permissions is to ask you for permissions that do not exist on CE, that's also a bug, but a much less serious one.

Comment: Well it's an implementation in the code. Tried running the query with a user with permissions  Bucket Full Access and Admin. Both returned the error I just added to the question

Comment: OK, I accept this as a bug. I expect it will be fixed in 6.5 CE. If connecting as administrator does not permit access to the system table, I can't think of a way to work around this problem in CE until the problem is fixed.